# Автоматическое заполнение пользователя в формах django

Tags: python, django

Есть модель Post, на основании которой создается форма PostForm и вьюха post_create.
Необходимо, чтобы имя автора поста автоматически подставлялось (создание поста доступно только авторизованному пользователю)

Модель

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts'
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        'Group',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

форма

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('text', 'group')
        widgets = {'author': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

вьюха

```
def post_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            form.author = request.user
            form = form.save()
            return redirect(f'/profile/{author}/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'posts/create.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'posts/create.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно initial поможет в вашем вопросе.

```
form = PostForm(request.POST, initial = {'author':request.user})
```

Comment: IntegrityError at /create/
NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_post.author_id