# Как при создании модельки нужно чтобы поле user автоматически выбиралось?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Проблема: при создании модельки в поле `user` выходит список всех пользователей которых ты можешь выбрать, а нужно что бы пользователь выбирался  автоматически

Comment: Прикрепите описание модели в виде кода и метод где происходит  создание этой модели, укажите конкретно какой юзер(юзеры) имеются и кого надо сохранять. Гадать никто не будет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1403383/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%85-django/1403486#1403486

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автоматическое заполнение пользователя в формах django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1403383/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%85-django)